# WordPress CLI error: Callable "Queue_Command" does not exist, and cannot be registered as `wp queue`

Tags: wp-cli

I have a server that hosts several WordPress sites. I use wpcli to update plugins in all of the sites, both manually and with a bash script.

One site has just started throwing an error:

```
Error: Callable "Queue_Command" does not exist, and cannot be registered as `wp queue`.
```

I have searched and found nothing at all that matches this error. Can anyone here explain what is causing it?

The site in question is running Wordpress 4.9.5 and WooCommerce 3.3.5, in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RESOLVED - the new Mailchimp for Woocommerce version 2.1.7 has this issue fixed

So far it seems like the issue is caused by Mailchimp for Woocommerce plugin. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cron-error-10/

Check if you have that plugin installed and see if removing/disabling it resolves the issue. After that we should check with the plugin developers if they can fix the actual cause of this.

Comment: Confirmed - thanks! Removing Mailchimp for Woocommerce version 2.1.6 and replacing it with version 2.17 resolved the issue.